# Parsing nested JSON data in an arrary

Tags: python, data-structures, jsonparser

Stuck trying to parse some nested JSON data:

```
"products": [
  {
   "id":123,
   "title": "Product 1",
   "handle": "product-1",
   "tags":[
      "tag--1",
      "tag--2",
      "tag--3"
    ],
   "variants":[
   {
    "id": 456
    "price": "7.50"
   }
]
}
```

Here is the code:

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
products = data['products']
prod = []
def get_tags():
    for items in products:
        title = items['title']
        handle = items['handle']
        v = products['variants'] #issue
        prodId = v['product_id']

        t = items['tags']
        t_filtered = [k for k in t if '--' in k]
        d = dict(s.split('--') for s in t_filtered)

        d['title'] = title
        d['handle'] = handle

        d['productId'] = prodId #issue

        prod.append(d)

        print(prod)
```

I get this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I know this is because the variants are nested and I am not reading the array[{ },{ }] like so, but I am not sure how to get around it. Any tips, tutorials?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `items['variants']`?

Comment: 1) `v = items['variants']` 2) `product_id` doesn't appear in your data, just `id`. 3) How do you want to handle 0 or multiple variants? Can you assume there's always exactly 1?

Comment: "I get this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" Okay, what happened when you tried looking at the line of code mentioned in the error? Do you understand what `list indices` are? Do you understand what a `TypeError` is? Do you understand what `integers`, `slices` and `str` are? Do you understand why a list index must be either an integer or a slice? According to your understanding of the error message, what kind of thing was used as a list index? Do you see why that is not valid? Do you see where it came from and why it has that type?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking `products['variants']` where there's no such key as `products` is a list of dicts. It should be:

```
v = items['variants']
```

Another issue is trying `prodId = v['product_id']` where `v` is a list of dict. So you need to iterate over `v` and access the `id` field as there exists no `product_id` field inside the dicts under `variants`. You should try:

```
prodId = [prod_vars['id'] for prod_vars in v]
```

I've noticed another issue in constructing `d` from splitting each entry in `t_filtered`. As the `tags` have `tag--something` format then only the **last** tag will be mapped in the line `d = dict(s.split('--') for s in t_filtered)`. If you're trying something like that, then it's okay. But you're trying to list all the tag numbers (right side of the '--') under a single key 'tag', then you should try:

```
d['tag'] = [s.split('--')[1] for s in t_filtered]
```

What I've understood, you're trying to create a list of products individually for each variant, where the variants have all the valid tags. If so, then you should iterate over the `prodId` list and construct individual dicts for each product. You can do this as follows:

```
for id in prodId:
    d = {}
    d['tag'] = [s.split('--')[1] for s in t_filtered]
    d['title'] = title
    d['handle'] = handle
    d['productId'] = id
    prod.append(d)
```

Your whole program will look like something like this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
products = data['products']
prod = []
def get_tags():
    for items in products:
        title = items['title']
        handle = items['handle']
        v = items['variants']
        prodId = [prod_vars['id'] for prod_vars in v]

        t = items['tags']
        t_filtered = [k for k in t if '--' in k]

        for id in prodId:
            d = {}
            d['tag'] = [s.split('--')[1] for s in t_filtered]
            print(d)
            d['title'] = title
            d['handle'] = handle
            d['productId'] = id
            prod.append(d)

    print(prod)
      
get_tags()
```

And you'll get a output like this:

```
[{'tag': ['1', '2', '3'], 'title': 'Product 1', 'handle': 'product-1', 'productId': 456}, {'tag': ['1', '2', '3'], 'title': 'Product 1', 'handle': 'product-1', 'productId': 457}]
```

Let me know if that is what you were expecting.

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thank you for breaking it down and explaining.

Comment: @madusha if you think this answer was helpful, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.